# Moderators can't delete spammers or puppets with attached Developer Stories

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, moderator-abilities

It appears that moderators cannot currently delete any accounts that have a Developer Story associated with them. We are locked out of all deletion options.

Unfortunately, this has prevented myself and other moderators from deleting sock puppets, spammers, and trolls who happened to have attached a Developer Story to their profile. For example, [this spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7037920/izofile) filled out [their Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/7037920) with spam and as a result I can't destroy them and feed them into the anti-spam system. I'm forced to lock their account behind a suspension.

Moderators should be able to delete troublesome accounts like this whether or not they have a Developer Story attached.

Comment: I foresee a grand future, where spammers and sock puppets create millions of full, beautiful backstories for their fake accounts. If they get good enough, I can feed the data to an author friend of mine and proclaim: "Mission f****** accomplished" https://xkcd.com/810/

Comment: I wonder - what's the benefit of advertising this fact with a meta-post?

Comment: @AaronHall it's just the place bugs go

Comment: Can anyone post a screenshots of that deleted developers story?

Comment: @AaronHall - I'm with you on this, I would have thought there would have been some mechanism for moderators to communicate moderator-specific systems issues privately.  Presumably doing it publicly gets it fixed quicker!

Comment: @McNab on SO pressure tactics are not really necessary, this would have been picked up as high priority regardless. If this is kept quiet however, it will likely result in many meta posts that describe the symptoms and will quickly unearth the source anyway. In other words: it just pays to put it out in the open right away.

Comment: @AaronHall Do you really think spammers read meta?

Comment: Bug reports, even on moderator tools, generally go here or on Meta.SE unless they involve private information. This makes things a little more consistent for SE developers. Because this only impacts Stack Overflow, I posted it here. It also serves to let other moderators know why this is happening, because many of us have independently hit this and couldn't figure out why we couldn't delete certain accounts. Anyone intentionally trying to circumvent account deletion after reading this will be dealt with appropriately.

Comment: This is becoming a huge problem. The spammers are already adapting, and so are the sockpuppets. We really need the ability to nuke bad accounts regardless of what's in their profiles or developer stories.

Comment: "destroy them and feed them into the anti-spam system" If only the anti-spam system was a giant shredder into which we literally tossed spamming human beings.

Comment: Let's keep these accounts and redirect badly behaving recruiters into this forest of resumes...

Comment: @SQB - Sockpuppets definitely do as we occasionally get Meta questions from them asking why all their rep suddenly disappeared.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Moderators can now destroy users with dev stories.

For some users, the Community Team will need to verify - this is now (Jan 16, 2017) automated, so just delete/destroy as normal.