# New Users aren't redirected to the Tour page. Should they be?

Tags: discussion, new-users, developer-story, tour-page

When composing this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336828/189134), I wanted to see if the [*Be Nice*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) page was displayed or linked for new users. (Spoiler: if it is, it's not obvious, because I didn't see it.)

What I found was that new users, who verify their email address, are not redirected to the Tour any longer. Instead, they are directed to fill out the Developer Story.

Is this expected? Should they be directed here (especially since [Mods can't delete these accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336489/189134) right now) or should they be shown the Tour page (or a combination of both?)

Comment: "Should" as in "is this by design" or "should" as in "is this what the 'community' would want to happen?"

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. At this time, this is the intended behavior; the Developer Story is part of the user profile and we are encouraging users to complete it.  However, we are looking as various paths for new users to move through post sign-up.

Q&A is no longer the only product on Stack Overflow. We've got Q&A, Documentation, and even Jobs, on the same site, so we're analyzing how users move through the sign-up process to determine what they will see immediately after sign-up.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's relavant that there's more to SO than Q&A. The point of funelling people through the tour was to ensure that we get high quality questions. Sure, feed them to the dev story too, but not at the expense of the tour. :)

Answer (score 22):

**Yes. Straight to the tour page with them.**

Also, new users being directed straight to the new jobs feature instead is bald-faced.

Comment: Especially since some of us (like me) aren't even open/allowed to get jobs yet.

Answer (score 5):

**No**. Straight to the [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), followed by the [ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with them.

The tour page just explains how voting works, not how to ask a good question.